# Issue while ALTER COLUMN in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I have table with id and name where id is the primary key with bigint as the datatype. Now I want to alter the column, where id as the primary key with auto incremented value.

My Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE test(
  testid bigint NOT NULL,
  testname character varying(255),
   CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (testid)
);
```

**Alter query:**

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN testid BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

After executing the query I'm getting the following error,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BIGSERIAL"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN testid BIGSERIAL P...
                                                         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "BIGSERIAL"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 50
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN key_column TYPE BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

i hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
--This will drop the primary key temporarily
ALTER TABLE test
drop CONSTRAINT test_pkey


--change data type
ALTER TABLE test
ALTER COLUMN testid BigInt


--add primary key
ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (testid )
```

Comment: The column is already exists in the table. I want to alter the same. Can you provide me the alter query instead add

Comment: please check the edited one.

Comment: I tried, getting the following error, ERROR: syntax error at or near "default"
SQL state: 42601